# Git track changes to external project

Tags: git

I have the following structure for my project.

```
- src/
 - .gitignore
 - lib
    - liba
    - libb
    - lib
    - libd
```

in my .`gitignore`, I asked to ignore `lib` folder. Assume `lib` contains external libraries like jquery, jqueryui,.. which has its own lifecycle. Unfortunately the tools I use require `lib` inside my `src` folder. Now, I need to make changes to `liba`. I don't want to track all the external projects in lib (except liba), but need to save my changes to liba. If I remove lib from .gitignore, that results in tracking the projects in lib. May be I could exclude one project only in .gitignore (option1), or git submodule may be the answer. option1 needs to exclude any libraries I may add to `lib` in the future rather than adding it manually every time to .gitignore. I read about submodule, but not sure is it posssible in my case as the external repo is within my src.

What is the best way to achieve this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore `lib`, except for `lib/liba`, you can structure your `.gitignore` like this:

```
/lib
!/lib/liba
```

This basically says to ignore everything in `lib` except for `lib/liba`. If there are only a few files (e.g. `*.h` files) in `lib/liba` that you want to track, you could take it a step further:

```
/lib
!/lib/liba/*.h
```

Although that won't catch files in subdirectories of `lib/liba`. To do that, you will probably need a second `.gitignore` in `lib/liba/.gitignore`. Then your main `.gitignore` would be like the first example, and your `lib/liba/.gitignore` would say:

```
*
!*.h
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git add -f` to explicitly add ignored items. That way you can leave your .gitignore as is but still track lib/liba.